# Dynamodb: No defined key schema. A key schema containing at least a hash key must be defined for all tables

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

When i tried creating a dynamodb table from C# using DocumentObject model. I encountered this error, did some search in internet but couldnt find the exact problem solved. The error is

```
No defined key schema.  A key schema containing at least a hash key must be defined for all tables
```

during creating a dynamotable after assigning all keyschemas.

Answer (score 0):

So was earlier successful in created a dynamo table in C# using the same .Net DocumentModel but this seems weird when tried to repeat in another project. The solution arrived when i compared both the working code and the error code.

```
                // coordindex
                var coordindex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex
                {
                    IndexName = "coordindex",
                    ProvisionedThroughput = new ProvisionedThroughput
                    {
                        ReadCapacityUnits = (long)10,
                        WriteCapacityUnits = (long)1
                    },
                    Projection = new Projection { ProjectionType = "ALL" }
                };
                useridindex.KeySchema = FeedTbl.tableKeySchema3;
```

This last line above is error creating one, but this error will throw during create table

```
 CreateTableResponse result = amazonDynamoDBclient.CreateTable(createTableRequest);
```

The solution is changing as follows

```
coordindex.KeySchema = FeedTbl.tableKeySchema3;
```

as the useridindex was assigned to previous tablekeyschema and coordindex schema was not assigned due to human error.

Hope this helps atleast someone.
Thanks
Cheers.